# Targeting a meta tag and its values with XPath in Google Sheets to follow flight data

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I have an event coming up where we have passengers coming in from 25-30 different flights for a week and I want to have the live data when it comes to their actual arrival time. I have their info lined up in a google sheets document and I want to extract the true arrival time from plane mapper.com or Schiphol.com. I've tried using https://www.planemapper.com/flights/AT850 as an example and tried to extract the data using =IMPORTXML(E88,"//meta[@itemprop='arrivaltime'][1]/@content") I have haven't had much luck however. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Another (free/low cost) solution would be great as well.

Thanks,

Bas

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=index(regexextract(substitute(textjoin("",,importxml(url,"//script")),char(10),""),"Arrival.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"),1)
```

it's a bit complex because you have to fetch data from the content of the script.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for commenting! I assume the "url" means I have to insert the url I want to extract the data from? Sorry I am an absolute noob when it comes to this kind of stuff

Comment: yes, but you can replace url by E88 for instance if url is located in cell E88.